# How to replace a Fragment when click n button in that fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a activity. in the activity have a fragmentholder. When application run, i show fragment_1. in fragment_1 , I have a button . when i click that button, the fragmentholder will change to fragment_2.

Comment: There are LOTS of examples out there. Please do some research first or show at least a bit of commitment by posting what you have done or tried first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. In your `Fragment1` create public interface named `OnFragment1ActiontListener` and handle logic in `onAttach()`

   ```
   public class Fragment1 {

       OnFragment1ActiontListener mCallback;

       // Container Activity must implement this interface
       public interface OnFragment1ActiontListener {
           public void onSwitchToFragment2();
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
          super.onAttach(activity);
          try {
             mCallback = (OnFragment1ActiontListener) activity;
          } catch (ClassCastException e) {
             throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + " must implement OnFragment1ActiontListener");
          }
       }

       // call this method when you click button
      public void onButtonClicked() {
         mCallback.onSwitchToFragment2();
      }
   }
   ```
2. In your activity, implement interface `OnFragment1ActiontListener`. It will be required to you `@Override` below method

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSwitchToFragment2() {
      // use fragmentholder to change to fragment2
     Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
     FragmentTransaction trs = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     trs.replace(R.id.fragmentholder, fragment);
     trs.commit();
   }
   ```

   Hope it help!

Comment: what is the different between using listener with FragmentTransaction and FragmentManager?

Comment: listener just using to communicate between fragment and activity.  I have updated the answer, take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create new fragment
Fragment newFragment = new NewFragment();

// Open transaction
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Mark as correct answer if it works for you! Thanks! @MariyaTha